# How to abort or stop JavaScript execution?

Tags: javascript, jquery, error-handling, compiler-errors

I am working in one example and that at some point(when something specific happen) to stop the execution of javascript code.

Here is the row where I detect the error(rows number 36 at the [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/orsina/2wvxrhqw/5/)):

```
  if(error_print === null){
                s += "errors+='"+"You have error in row :" + (i+1) + "';";
                //here I want to stop the code execution

            } else{ //continue...}
```

So I want:

1- to stop the code execution when this error is detected

2- to clean the `#output textarea` from the messages that are print before

(so if the error occured I want only to have the message error in the `#errors` textarea). So I dont want the `#output` text area to have this values:

```
This " is my first program 
My name is XXX
```

but I want it to be empty after error detection.

I have tried to use `return;` and `throw new Error('You have an error');` but these have not function. Please can you help me? Thanks in advance.

[Here is the demo you can play with.](https://jsfiddle.net/orsina/2wvxrhqw/5/)

Comment: throw an exception and catch in an outer try/catch block

Comment: @cory in fact I am not familiar with this concept. Can you please help me? Suggesting something where to start reading would help me. Thanks

Comment: I doubt you really want to stop code execution, as that would prevent step 2 from being possible.

Comment: @Kevin thanks. But how can I achive at the sam etime step 1 and step 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, allow me to make a few remarks on the code in your fiddle:

- an if inside a while inside an if inside an if inside an if inside a function, ... That is just horrible code to read and bugs waiting to happen. Please refactor that code (work with early returns, divide it up into functions, ...). My rule of thumb is never nest more then 2 levels deep. Good written code should document itself, and I can't realy say your code is self explanatory.
- Why are you inserting that script bloc? I see no need for that at all. It is almost as bad as using eval()...
- try to use sensible variable names. `s` may seem clear at the moment you are writing the code, but I promise you it won't in six months when you have to go and hunt down a bug.

Note that I am just trying to help you here, not trying to break you down.

As for your question, why don't you just keep a error boolean somewhere. Default it to false and set it to true when an error occurs. Before outputting your result, just s-check the state of that boolean. When it is true, don't output anything. That should be by far the easiest solution imo.

```
var hasErrors = false;
...
// an error occurs
if (this.notRight) { hasErrors = true; }
...
if (! hasErrors) {
   $('#output').html(output);
}
```

Comment: thanks for your idea. In fact I know that my code is really messy:( and of course I understand that you are trying to help me... I will try to organize it now. Thanks again